# Wpf DataGrid - Show text as link based on text content

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I've done some research,but haven't found any solution to my problem.
Based on the context of the bound text property, I have to show data as normal text or as a link, which should be clickable and bound to a command.

Do I have to create 2 data templates and a template selector to achieve this goal, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Your suggestion to use two data templates is a good approach and is not so complicated as it seems at first look.

Comment: Of course as a straight and easy approach you can create two versions of your text for every cell but show only one of them using `Visibility` property (For small grids the overhead will not be so big).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to create 2 data templates and a template selector to achieve this goal, or is there an easier way?

You could use a `ContentControl` with a `DataTemplate` per type of `DataContext`, e.g.:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Type1}">
            <TextBlock>...</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Type2}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://stackoverflow.com">Link...</Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```